# Merging partitions separated by Bootcamp

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

In the process of installing windows on my MacBook Pro, I managed to somehow partition the disk this way.

[image]

Is there any way of merging the `UNTITLED 3` segment with the Macintosh HD segment without reinstalling windows?

Answer (score 1):

Select Untitled 3 partition and delete it (click the minus button). Now you can extend the size of the Macintosh HD by dragging the resize bar at the bottom right it can extend to take up the space formerly occupied by Untitled 3 and it won't affect your bootcamp partition.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to merge partitions with Disk Utility. You can resize/extend partitions for your Macintosh HD, but not for Bootcamp.

If you look at [this](http://guides.macrumors.com/Extend/Resize_Boot_Camp_Partition) link, it gives you several options for programs that will resize your bootcamp partitions. All of them involve cloning your Windows installation and then restoring it back on a partition after you delete both partitions and then tell `Boot Camp Assistant` to make a new partition for Windows 7. After, you can simply restore the cloned Windows 7 image back onto the partition and it will boot up with the extra space.

I have used this process myself to extend my Bootcamp partition. I used `WinClone`.

### Other Links

1. [Resize BootCamp Windows 7](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1312171)- the user also recommends WinClone, because it is just safer to do and you will not lose any data.
2. [Other Options](https://discussions.apple.com/message/15922212#15922212)- Apple Discussion Board

Comment: I think he wants to merge the empty partition back into his Mac partition not bootcamp.

Comment: Mike, I realized this as well awhile after I posted my answer. Thank you for posting your answer, since it directly answers the OP's question. Mine is less relevant, but I will leave it here for others to see.

Answer (score 0):

If you had used BootCamp to create partitions for windows, you could use bootcamp to remove those partitions as well. Just open bootcamp and one out of options would say "merge existing partitions etc..."